# creating a "player" from a list of names and giving them their own independent lists

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently learning about classes and methods in python and am stuck in a small project im doing,
I want to create "players" from a list of player names, each of these players need their own independant lists (hand, up, down) I thought this below would achieve this

```
deck = ["ha", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8", "h9", "h10", "hj", "hq", "hk", "da", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "d8", "d9", "d10", "dj", "dq", "dk"]

cardsperset = 3

playernames = ["N", "L"]

class player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        hand = []
        up = []
        down = []

for name in playernames:
    name = player(name)

def randomcard():
    randcard = deck[random.randint(range(deck))]
    deck.remove(randcard)
    return randcard

for i in range(cardsperset):
    N.hand.append(randomcard())
    N.down.append(randomcard())
    N.up.append(randomcard())

print(N.hand)
```

However when trying to print the result to see if this worked I am getting the error "NameError: name 'N' is not defined"
obviously the creation of the player "N" was not successful, am i going about this the wrong way ?

Comment: You never define `N = ...`, so `N` doesn't exist in scope. `name = player(name)` doesn't update the value in the list of `playernames` either. It overrides the local variable `name` which is then overridden again in the next iteration.

Comment: you probably should have `N = player('N')` somewhere...

Comment: so how could i go about defining N as a player, from it being in the list, rather than just making N manually

Comment: @hiroprotagonist yes but the name wont always be N, is there a way of making a player and giving it the name from the list ? I thought that the for loop would make that possible as for every name make the name = player(name)

Comment: you could create a `dict`: `players = {name: player(name) for name in playernames}`. then you can refer to them as `players['N']`.

Comment: thats great, so i can still refer to them by the name they inputted too,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each player should be assigned `cardsperset` number of cards, you should first ensure you have a list of the players created - and then you can iterate this list, assigning random cards to each player.

I made some additional changes, like capital class name (player -> Player), changing `hand = []` to `self.hand = []`, etc.

```
import random

deck = ["ha", "h2", "h3", "h4", "h5", "h6", "h7", "h8", "h9", "h10", "hj", "hq", "hk", "da", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "d8", "d9", "d10", "dj", "dq", "dk"]

cardsperset = 3

playernames = ["N", "L"]
players = []
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.hand = [] # assign to self
        self.up = []
        self.down = []

for name in playernames:
    players.append(Player(name)) # Append players to global list "players"

def randomcard():
    randcard = deck[random.randint(0, len(deck)-1)]
    deck.remove(randcard)
    return randcard

for N in players: # for each player, N, assign cards. N now exists in scope.
  for i in range(cardsperset):
      N.hand.append(randomcard())
      N.down.append(randomcard())
      N.up.append(randomcard())

print(players[0].hand) # Access a certain player and inspect hand.
```

Comment: you are a genius, me being stupid wanted the names of the players to be specific, but that doesnt actually matter. so in this the players are created and are just "called" their index in the players list,
Thanks for the help

Comment: @NathanBoswell-Holmes You could also go by [@hiro protagonist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4954037/hiro-protagonist)'s solution of storing players in a `dict` with name as key. Note that you can't have duplicate player-names though. Feel free to accept if you think it solved your problem. :-)